# Как спарсить данные если их нет в html?

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Мне нужно спарсить эту страничку https://www.flashscore.com/match/ETiJbUxd/#/h2h/overall
Скачал html сайта но там нет нужных данных ( голы, прошлые игры итд)
Вместо них какой то js скрипт
пытался ловить api но в networke ничего нет

подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Данные внутри jsx - динамические. Чтобы их достать, - потребуется скрапер. Например - Selenium webdriver.
https://pypi.org/project/selenium/

Comment: Парсить через Selenium так себе идея. Это долго и инструмент не для этого.

Comment: Тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, быстрый способ парсинга динамических данных из скриптов. Мне бы пригодилось.

Comment: надо смотреть что отработает, в большинстве случаев достаточно библиотек **httpx** / **requests_html** и пр. Но, если всё это не отработает, можно и через Selenium. Просто Selenium очень долгий и его поведение не всегда предсказуемо, например при скроллинге.