# При парсинге берется английская версия сайта

Tags: парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, re

Пишу парсер, который должен брать дату окончания скидки, но почему-то берется именно английская версия сайта, хотя accept-language указан в headers. Помогите пожалуйста парсить русские данные!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def get_data(url):
    headers = {
        'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                      'Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

    }

    req = requests.get(url, headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    date = soup.find('p', class_='game_purchase_discount_countdown').text
    regex_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})\s+(\w+)'

    match = re.search(regex_pattern, date)

    if match:
        day = match.group(1)
        month = match.group(2).capitalize()
        print(f"{day} {month}")
    

get_data("https://store.steampowered.com/app/552500/Warhammer_Vermintide_2/")
```

Вывод:

```
25 April
```

Comment: Попробуйте ограничится 'Accept-Language': 'ru-RU,ru'. Возможно, решит проблему.

Comment: @Teslajke, спасибо за ответ! К сожалению не помогло

Comment: Вряд ли что-то выйдет по крайней мере без селениума, там при переключении языка идет дополнительный запрос `https://store.steampowered.com/account/setlanguage/` c `language=russian&sessionid=bcad12c2f65ecdb55fb12666`, если нужна только дата, проще написать функцию которая русифицирует месяц:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Daniil Loban, зря вы так, конечно… Всё тут очень даже замечательно получается, причём очень просто в отличие от [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1514021/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%A2%D0%9F-steam-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%85), где курсы грузятся через backend настройки. И Selenium использовать для парсинга — ну [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1512160/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-html/1512174#comment2714516_1512174).

Тут же всё, прям, чудесно.
Повторим минимально код:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get('https://store.steampowered.com/app/552500/Warhammer_Vermintide_2/')
soup = BS(r.content, 'lxml')

regex_pattern = r'(\d{1,2})\s+(\w+)'

offer = soup.find('p', class_='game_purchase_discount_countdown').text
date = re.search(regex_pattern, offer)[0] 
print(date)
```

###### Вывод:

```
25 April
```

Предсказуемо.
Как видите, даже не стал заморачиваться с **headers**. А теперь, посмотрим, что произойдёт при логине на стим и смене языка! Долго копать не пришлось, идём в лисичку и смотрим [cookie](/questions/tagged/cookie), там вопиющее название `Steam_Language`. Забираем его, и добавляем куку, более подробно про их создание говорил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1513272/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wildberries/1513985#1513985).

```python
s.cookies.set('Steam_Language', 'russian', domain='store.steampowered.com')
```

Получаем страницу заново, парсер, регулярка и‥ получаем **25 апреля**, ура!

---

#### Альтернатива

Но, как вам правильно подсказали, если совсем не получается, то надо искать альтернативы. Ну, например, [перевести](https://deep-translator.readthedocs.io/):

```python
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
translated = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='ru').translate(date)
print(translated)
```

###### Вывод:

```
25 апреля
```

B общем то, тут можно закончить ответ, получили то что хотели, мы это получили ещё раньше с куками, но т.к. наш русский язык любимый замечательный и сложный, при переводе может получиться не так всё чудесно, например если убрать **25** или если переводчик не догадается поставить правильный падеж:

```python
translated = GoogleTranslator(source='en', target='ru').translate(date[3:])
print(translated)
```

###### Вывод:

```
апрель
```

Бах, апрел**ь**.
Именительный падеж. На самом деле ситуация довольно популярная при переводе и не только. Что можно сделать?
Использовать [pymorphy](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/):

```python
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
morphed = morph.parse(translated)[0].inflect({'gent'}).word
print(morphed)
```

###### Вывод:

```
апреля
```

Так что, используем куки и умеем в альтернативу

---

###### UPD

Перед тем как закрыть браузер ещё раз заглянул, какие там cookies есть. Очень интересным также оказался `timezoneOffset`, рекомендую его тоже добавить, т.к. с датой работаем.